# How to build or install WebKitGTK on CentOS 5.8?

Tags: gtk, webkit

I'm trying to build an embedded simple web browser for an embedded device and I've decided to use WebKit / WebKitGTK+. However, our device uses a Linux environment somewhat based on CentOS 5.8. I haven't been able to find any RPMS or mention of support for WebKit / WebKitGTK+ for CentOS 5.8 while doing several web searches.

Does anybody know if it's possible to build an older version of WebKitGTK+ for CentOS 5.8 such as 1.2.6-2.el6_0 which works well on CentOS 6.3? Are any RPMS available for CentOS 5.8?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that it is possible to build a given software package on a given OS version.  It might take a lot of work assembing all the necessary packages at the right release level, and then having to install these files in non-standard locations.  You still have an integration job in that things still have to be tested to make sure the standard library set still works with this compiled setup....then back to getting appropriate source tars at the right level and compiling and loading with these...and on and on...

Don't get me wrong, I have personally done this a long time ago in my career but now I don't and try to keep using the more updated things or packages that are generated for the specific vendor release system.  Saves me a lot of time and effort.

In otherwords, you have a job ahead of you.  Good luck.